# Sorting a SortedDictionary based on value, not key

Tags: c#

I have a SortedDictionary, the key is a int value and the matching value to each key is a class object. The class contains a int and a two datetime variable.

I need to sort my SortedDictionary based on the InTime datetime in my class. So that when I do a foreach to loop through my SortedDictionary I will have them sorted based on datetime.

Is this possible? How can I achieve it?

```
enter code here
 class Busdetail
    {
        public int BusNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime InTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime OutTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-dictionary-by-value

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET SortedDictionary But Sorted By Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619051/net-sorteddictionary-but-sorted-by-values)

Answer (score 12):

Sorted Dictionary will always sort on the key, so there is no way to re-arrange it's data so they are sorted on anything other that the key. What you can do is get the data into another structure (some kind of `IOrderedEnumerable`) where they can be sorted on things other that the key.

If you want to discard the keys and just get the values then

```
var sortedValues = dictionary.Values.OrderBy(busDetail => busDetail.InTime);
```

will work, and the type of sortedValues will be `IOrderedEnumerable<BusDetail>`.
If you still need to keep both the keys and values, you could do:

```
var sortedElements = dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.InTime);
```

which will return a `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, BusDetail>>`.
You can that `foreach` on any of these two collections, or you could bind them to a grid's datasource.

Comment: To sort the dictionary each time you enter or remove from it?

Answer (score 3):

SortedDictionary can't be sorted by value, though you can extract a sorted list of values, as the other answers point out.

What you want to do is use a list of keyvaluepairs instead, then sort that, like so:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, BusDetail>> busses = GetMyListOfBusses();
busses.Sort((first, next) => { 
     return first.Value.InTime.CompareTo(next.Value.Intime); 
});
```

At that point, your keyvaluepair list of busses will be sorted by InTime

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use SortedSet and Tuple of your key and value, like:
SortedSet> ((a,b)=>(a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2));

Comment: This will break the set property of the sorted set. This causes the set to accept the same value twice (key = x, value = 10) (key = x, value = 5). It breaks the set in the sense that he may want the dictionary property of only having unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Linq query.

```
var D = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
var qD = from kvp in D
         orderby kvp.Value
         select kvp
;
```