# SortedDictionary: Key-identification different from sorting?

Tags: .net, sorting, dictionary

AFAIK the `IComparer` of the `SortedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` is responsible for the sorting of the elements AND key identification.

What I want is to sort with another function than the function which identifies the keys.
Is there a way to do this with the `SortedDictionary`?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorted Dictionary will always sort on the key, so there is no way to re-arrange it's data so they are sorted on anything other that the key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417296/sorting-a-sorteddictionary-based-on-value-not-key