# Sorting a Dictionary by Value

Tags: vb.net, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the form of:

```
{ "honda" : 4, "toyota": 7, "ford" : 3, "chevy": 10 }
```

I want to sort it by the second column aka (the value) descending.

Desired output:

> "chevy", 10
>
> "toyota", 7
>
> "honda", 4
>
> "ford", 3

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to caryden from:
[How do you sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-dictionary-by-value/1332#1332)

```
Dim sortedDict = (From entry In dict Order By entry.Value Descending Select entry)
```

The issues reported above were due to improper looping.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if it is HashTable, it can not be sorted.
On the other hand, if you have an ArrayList or any other collection that can be sorted, you can implement your own IComparer.

```
  public class MyDicComparer : IComparer
  {
    public int Compare(Object x, Object y)
    {
      int Num1= ((Dictionary)x).Value;   // or whatever
      int Num2= ((Dictionary)y).Value;

      if (Num1 < Num2) return 1;
      if (Nun1 > Num2) return -1;
      return 0;  // Equals, must be consideres
    }

ArrayList AL;
...
AL.Sort(MyDicComparer);
```

HTH

Comment: Get an error on "implements IComparer":
    Public Class MyDictComparer
        Implements IComparer
        Public Function Compare(ByVal x As [Object], ByVal y As [Object]) As Integer
            Dim Num1 As DictionaryEntry = DirectCast(x, DictionaryEntry)
            Dim Num2 As DictionaryEntry = DirectCast(y, DictionaryEntry)
            If CInt(Num1.Value) < CInt(Num2.Value) Then
                Return 1
            End If
            If CInt(Num1.Value) > CInt(Num2.Value) Then
                Return -1
            End If
            Return 0
        End Function
    End Class

Comment: Error message: 
Class 'CountValueComparer' must implement 'Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer' for interface 'System.Collections.IComparer'.