# VB.Net Order a Dictionary(Of String, Integer) by value of the Integer

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have a dictionary of String, Integer so the key is the string and the value is the integer and i want to order the keys ascending by the value of the integer. How could I achieve this?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a Dictionary by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671236/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) to sort the `Dictionary` by value:

```
Dim dictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)() 
dictionary.Add("A", 2)
dictionary.Add("B", 4)
dictionary.Add("C", 5)
dictionary.Add("D", 3)
dictionary.Add("E", 1)

Dim sorted = From pair In dictionary
             Order By pair.Value
Dim sortedDictionary = sorted.ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key, Function(p) p.Value)
```

Actually it does not modify the original Dictionary but creates a new Dictionary with the new order.

**But**: Apart from the feasability, a `Dictionary` is not an `IList` (as an Array or `List<T>`). It's purpose is to lookup a key very efficiently but not to loop all entries.

They are unordered, meaning that although you can retrieve the elements in some order with a foreach loop, that order has no special meaning, and it might change for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, a dictionary does not have an intrinsic order.  It is for look-ups.  However, you can turn the keys into their own ordered list.

```
Dim keyList as List(Of String) = (From tPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) _
                                  In myDictionary Order By tPair.Value Ascending _
                                  Select tPair.Key).ToList
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to do something similar to this with custom objects. I think this should be close (but may not be exactly) what you're looking for:

```
Dim sortedL As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) = yourDictionary.ToList
sortedL.Sort(Function(firstPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer), nextPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) CInt(firstPair.Value).CompareTo(CInt(nextPair.Value)))
```

Comment: Steve, why would you discourage greeting the person who asked the question, and signing an abbreviation for my name?

Comment: I rolled it back to Steve's version.  Signatures are discouraged and the greeting is unnecessary.

Comment: It clutters up the questions and answers with unnecessary chatter which is useless to others down the road who may stumble upon this question in search for an answer to their problem.  Personal greetings are typically discouraged and tag lines are explicitly mentioned in the FAQ as being bad etiquette on this site.  I'm sure if you look around the site, you'll find that is typically the case, even in the other answers to this question.

Comment: Great! I totally agree with eliminating my tagline...but the greeting? I think the greeting is a kind way of introducing a solution (and nothing is said against this in the Etiquette section). These are, after all, people we're talking to. I wouldn't jump into conversation without first greeting the person I'm talking to.