# Convert an IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> into a Dictionary<string, int>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I was following the [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-dictionary-by-value/1332#1332), and I got:

```
// itemCounter is a Dictionary<string, int>, and I only want to keep
// key/value pairs with the top maxAllowed values
if (itemCounter.Count > maxAllowed) {
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> sortedDict =
        from entry in itemCounter orderby entry.Value descending select entry;
    sortedDict = sortedDict.Take(maxAllowed);
    itemCounter = sortedDict.ToDictionary<string, int>(/* what do I do here? */);
}
```

Visual Studio's asking for a parameter `Func<string, int> keySelector`. I tried following a few semi-relevant examples I've found online and put in `k => k.Key`, but that gives a compiler error:

> `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>>'`
>   does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   `'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>,
>   System.Func<TSource,TKey>)'` has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You are specifying incorrect generic arguments. You are saying that TSource is string, when in reality it is a KeyValuePair.

This one is correct:

```
sortedDict.ToDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, int>, string, int>(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

with short version being:

```
sortedDict.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaboration! So in C#, `pair => pair.Key` is of type `Func`? How do you declare one of those? (So that one could do `sortedDict.ToDictionary(funcKey, funcVal);`?)

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest you not use C# LINQ syntax because it kind of hides from you what methods you really call, and looks alien for C# language. I never use it because I think it's ugly.

Your sample could be written in C# without linq like this: `sortedDict = itemCounter.OrderByDescending(entry => entry.Value)`. Not longer, right?

Comment: I don't see a `OrderByDescending` method for `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the cleanest way of doing both together: sorting the dictionary and converting it back to a dictionary would be:

```
itemCounter = itemCounter.OrderBy(i => i.Value).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is too old but still would like to give answer for reference:

```
itemCounter = itemCounter.Take(maxAllowed).OrderByDescending(i => i.Value).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
```

Comment: This won't return the expected results, as you are doing the `Take` before you have done the sort