# How to find minimum key in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I declare dictionary as following:

```
private Dictionary<int, touchInformation> touchDictionary = new Dictionary<int, touchInformation>();
```

And I used as following:

`touchDictionary[touchID]` = touchObject;

So, the touchDictionary will keep the key from touchID. Now, I try to find the minimum key using dictionary but I don't know how to do. Have any suggestion?

Regard,
C.Porawat

Comment: Could you explain your use case here?  What is the benefit of knowing the min?

Comment: An alternative way of doing this, is to store the "Current" minimum value and on every add/remove from the dictionary, check against this and update if necessary.  It'll stop the enumeration of the keys.

Comment: Have you considered if a `SortedList<,>` or `SortedDictionary<,>` is a better fit for your collection? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z658b67.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to check boolean value in all object in dictionary.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Dictionary has a Keys property which allows you to enumerate the keys within the dictionary. You can use the Min Linq extension methods to get the minimum key as follows:

```
int minimumKey = touchDictionary.Keys.Min();
```

Comment: And unfortunately, the is an O(n) operation.  You get none of the benefits of having a dictionary here.

Comment: Maybe wrap your dictionary in a class that can keep a record of the min key used to make entries?

Comment: There is nothing in the original question that indicates that this is a performance sensitive operation!

Answer (score 0):

Something like `touchDictionary.Keys.Min()`. Just make sure you import the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer inn this post on SO:

[How do you sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-dictionary-by-value)

You would just need to sort by Key instead