# VB.net sort and retain keys

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I have a situation where I need to sort arrays and preserve the current key - value pairs.

For example, this array:

```
(0) = 4
(1) = 3
(2) = 1
(3) = 2
```

Needs to sort like this

```
(2) = 1
(3) = 2
(1) = 3
(0) = 4
```

Retaining the original keys. Array.Sort(myArray) sorts into the right sequence but doesn't keep the indexes. I need a variant that does.

**edit**
Using the links, this seems close to what I want. Do I just need to remove the extra brackets to convert this to vb.net?

```
myList.Sort((firstPair,nextPair) =>
    {
        return firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value);
    }
);
```

(also would I intergrate this as a function or something else?)

Comment: You can use a Dictionary.  Here's a SO answer on the topic.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-dictionary-by-value

Comment: That seems to be related to C#. Are they compatible? (sorry, new to vb.net)

Comment: Yes. They use a different syntax, but they're (basically) the same language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using .net 2.0 (since you said that you are using Visual Studio 2005 in one of the comments), using an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) might be an option for you, **if** every array value appears only once. Since OrderedDictionaries are ordered by the key, you could add your array entries to such a dictionary, using

- the *array index* as the *dictionary value* and
- the *array value* as the *dictionary key* (which will be used to order the dictionary).

Comment: If you mean that no value can be the same as another - I can't guarantee that (in fact it's quite likely). Fast getting the feeling net 2.0 is antiquated, and upgrading is out of my control. What is the newest version?

Comment: @YsoL8: The newest version is 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010). Visual Studio 2008 support 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

In an array, the order is determined by the indexes (what you call "keys"). Thus, there cannot be an array like this:

```
(2) = 1
(3) = 2
(1) = 3
(0) = 4
```

What you need is a data structure that has *keys*, *values* and an *order* (which is independent from the keys). You can use a `List(Of KeyValuePair)` or (if you use .net 4) `List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer))` for this; a few examples are shown in the link provided by Ken in the comment (which I will repeat here for convenience):

- [How do you sort a C# dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-dictionary-by-value)

---

**EDIT**: Another option would be to use LINQ to automatically create a sorted `IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer))`:

```
Dim a() As Integer = {4, 3, 1, 2}  ' This is your array

Dim tuples = a.Select(Function(value, key) New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)(key, value))
Dim sorted = tuples.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Item2)
```

(untested, don't have Visual Studio available right now)

Comment: copy/pasting directly into visual studio generates errors I don't know how to resolve

Comment: @YsoL8: Do you understand the code? If no, where are you lost? (And if you don't tell me *which* errors you get, I cannot help you resolve them... ;-))

Comment: @Heninzi I get end of statement expected declaring the contents of the array on line 1 and line 2 starting at the new keyword. I also get expression expected on both function keywords. I am pasting this in a sub in a class.

Comment: @YsoL8: Ah, the array initializer syntax was broken. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @heninzi That cleared the error on line 1. The others remain however. (I am trying to resolve them this end, just not sucessfully). Does t need to be dim'ed?

Comment: @YsoL8: Nope, t is a parameter of the lambda. What error do you get?

Comment: Dim tuples = a.Select(Function(ByVal value, ByVal key) New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)(key, value)) clears the end of statement error starting on new but adds one under the second ByVal. No idea why.

Comment: I get expression expected for the function keywords and end of statement expected under the second ByVal in the fix I attempted.

Comment: @Ysol8: You definitely don't need the ByVal keywords here. Do you have Option Infer activated for your project?

Comment: don't know how to activate it - so I guess not

Comment: @YsoL8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx, see the section "To set Option Infer in the IDE".

Comment: @Henizi I'm using Visual Studio 2005 which apparently doesn't support Option Infer.

Comment: @YsoL8: Ah, ok, so you're targeting .net 2.0, which does not support lambdas nor LINQ either. Sorry, then my solution (and most others that you'll find here) won't work.

Comment: Ok. a) sorry for wasting your time b) good to know for the future c) bugger

Comment: @Ysol8: No problem. I've added another answer, which works on .net 2 and might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is storing it as a Dictionary < int,int > and sort by the dictionary by Value.

I think the VB .Net synatx for dictionary is Dictionary( of Int, Int)

Comment: found: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-dictionary-vbnet. Will try and post text if good solution