# How to sort dictionary by DateTime attribute of the value

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, sorting, dictionary

Here is my try

```
public MyClass
{
   public Guid ID {set; get;}
   public DateTime CreatedDateTime {set; get;}
}


ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, MyClass> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid,MyClass>();
```

I try this but I got some trouble...

```
dic.OrderBy(i=>i.Value.CreatedDateTime);
```

I got an error like

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable'
```

Any clue? Thanks!!

Comment: it doesnt really make sense to sort a dictionary... the values are not stored like that

Comment: @Muad'Dib So how do i have to sort this Dictionary? Could u help pls?

Comment: dictionary does not implement IOrderdEnumerable, so you cant use OrderBy() on it. items in a dictionary are stored in an arbitrary order, there is no concept of a "first" element and a "last" element, so you cant really sort it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you sort a C# dictionary by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-sharp-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `dic.Values.OrderBy(i=>i.CreatedDateTime)`