# Sort Descending directly

Tags: c#, sorting

I have

```
List<string> strs;
double[] values;
```

where the values array contains the value of each of the string in strs list

Say `strs={"abc","def","ghi"}`
and `values={3,1,2}`
this means "abc" has value 3 and so on.

I wish to sort strs and values ordered by values, such that it becomes

```
strs={"def","ghi","abc"}
values={3,2,1}
```

I am using

```
string[] strsArr = strs.ToArray();
Array.Sort(values, strsArr);//1. sort it ascendingly
strs = strsArr.ToList();
Array.Reverse(strs);//2. reverse it
```

Is there a way I can sort it in descending sequence directly without 2 phases?

Comment: Just curious why you aren't using a Dictionary<string, double> since you're essentially creating a map. Then you can follow the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-sharp-dictionary-by-value

Comment: `SortedDictionary` would be the way to do.

Comment: @IAbstract Looks like he wants to sort by the values though. SortedDictionary sorts by keys.

Comment: @william007: sorting by *descending* value means that your values would be sorted like so: `3, 2, 1`. If you want your values, as you state in your expected results, to be `1, 2, 3` then you are sorting by *ascending* value.

Comment: @IAbstract You are right, I have edited the question, thanks for the pointing of mistake ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Dictionary and Linq to solve this.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>() 
{ 
           {"abc",3}, 
           {"def",1}, 
           {"ghi",2} 
};
var sorted = dict.OrderByDescending(g => g.Value)
                 .Select(g => g.Key)
                 .ToArray();
```

Note, unless you have a ToArray() at the end the sorting will be deferred till later enumerated and may accidentally be enumerated multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var strs = new [] { "abc", "def", "ghi", };
var values = new [] { 3, 1, 2, };

strs =
    strs
        .Zip(values, (s, v) => new { s, v })
        .OrderByDescending(sv => sv.v)
        .Select(sv => sv.s)
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I think you forgot to extract just the string part, right now the result type isn't compatible.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Yes, you're right. Copy & paste error. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

try use dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
dictionary.Add("abc", 3);
dictionary.Add("def", 1);
dictionary.Add("ghi", 2);

var sortedDict = dictionary.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);
double[] values = sortedDict.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
List<string> strs = sortedDict.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```