# Sort dictionary by value

Tags: c#, mono

I'd like to order a dictionary by the value. It seems the way it would usually be done in .Net doesn't exist in the Mono API.

Is there any particular API call or should I do this myself?

Thanks

Comment: What is "the way it would usually be done in .Net"? Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: It seems that you haven't search the net yet.

Comment: If it's a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<,>`, then the dictionary in itself has no particular ordering, hence cannot be sorted. If you want an `IEnumerable<>` (sequence) with the key/value pairs of the dictionary such that the `IEnumerable<>` is sorted, use e.g. LINQ method `OrderBy`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-sharp-dictionary-by-value .@Guy I did, nothing that worked in Mono came up.

Comment: @steve: And what about that does *not* work in Mono? The code provided in the accepted answer to that question compiles and runs for me with `mcs`/`gmcs` and `mono` without any compiler/runtime errors, respectively. (checked with Mono 2.10.9 on Win 7 x64)

Comment: Hrm... our mono V must be out of date. It throws compilation error for me. Not sure which version of Mono we're using, just that its on linux (shouldnt matter I assume)

Comment: @steve: What is the error message? (Please make sure to write `@` and my user name in front of your replies, or else I won't be notified about your messages and will find them only by chance.)

Comment: @steve: Also, you can determine the version of your Mono installation with `mono --version`.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, the Dictionary class has no ordering. If you want a Dictionary that is ordered, there is the [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) class.

But the SortedDictionary is ordered by it's keys. Keeping an ordering dictionary by it's values doesn't seem an usual task.

Anyway, if you want to access the values sorted you could do:

```
dict.Values.OrderBy(v => v).ToList(); //Sorted list of the values of the dictionary dict
```

or

```
dict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList(); //Sorted list (by value) of the key value pairs of the dictionary dict
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Linq:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var sorted = dict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```