# c# Dictionary<char,int> picking the key with the largest value

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<char, int> charstat` to count occurrences of a character. I want to get the 5 most common character counts from this dictionary. How do go about doing this.

Some example data:

```
 <'T', 1>
 <'A', 2>
 <'C', 5>
 <'Q', 10>
 <'B', 3>
 <'Z', 7>
```

And from this I want to get in order of the largest count:

```
Q
Z
C
B
A
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you sort a C# dictionary by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-sharp-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: By "5 most common character counts", do you mean the most common values, or the highest values?

Comment: Highest values indicated by the integer value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to get the 5 most common character counts from this dictionary.

```
var item = charstat.OrderByDescending(r => r.Value)
                          .Select(r => r.Key)
                          .Take(5);
```

Comment: @Rawling Before editing code in question was invalid that was making this solution invalid as well. That might be a reason. +1 from me anyway.

Comment: @PLB, I didn't have `Select` clause, so it was originally selecting the dictionary item. now edited it to select the key.

Comment: Of course, if there's a tie, i.e. some values are equal, it is undefined which order these come in.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Dictionary<char, int> dir = new Dictionary<char, int>();
  // ...
  var query = (from p in dir
              orderby p.Value descending
              select p).Take(5);
  foreach (var item in query) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Char: {0}, Count: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
  }
```