# Sort through a dictionary and concatenate values depending on keys

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, arrays

I have a dictionary object

```
Dictionary<double, byte[]>
```

that has keys such as 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 3.0, 4.0, ...

I need to concatenate the values (byte[]) such that values with keys 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 is one byte[], values with keys 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4 is one byte[], and so forth.

I am able to get the number of bytearrays I need to end up with but there has to be a more efficient way than how I am trying to do this.

```
var keys = chunkedStates.Keys;
List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
foreach(var key in keys)
            {
                var Id = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(key));
                if (!Ids.Contains(Id))
                {
                    Ids.Add(Id);
                }
            }
```

So Ids.Count represents the number of bytearrays I should have after the concatenation. But I am stuck as to how to proceed from here...

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: `double` makes a **terrible, terrible** dictionary key, btw; keys depend on exact equality; and the one thing you rarely have with `double`: exact equality

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for the tip. Will fix.

Comment: @MarcGravell, please tell can we use `SortedDictionary` here? Also what if you actually need something like this with `double`?

Comment: @HassanNisar `SortedDictionary` will handle the *ordering* issue (although it has different costs); it won't handle the rest of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dictionary<int, byte[]> results = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
    foreach(var grp in data.OrderBy(pair => pair.Key)
               .GroupBy(pair => (int)pair.Key, pair => pair.Value))
    {
        byte[] result;
        if (grp.Count() == 1)
        {
            result = grp.Single();
        }
        else {
            result = new byte[grp.Sum(arr => arr.Length)];
            int offset = 0;
            foreach(byte[] arr in grp)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(arr, 0, result, offset, arr.Length);
                offset += arr.Length;
            }
        }
        results.Add(grp.Key, result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ToLookup`:

```
ILookup<int, double> lookup = keys.ToLookup(d => (int)d);
```

If you want a `List<int[]>` where each entry contains all doubles for that integer:

```
List<double[]> bytes = lookup
            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(d => d).ToArray())
            .ToList();
```

But note that you should not use double as key in a dictionary since it does not repsent exact values but a dictionary needs to have exact keys, otherwise you don't find them or you get exceptions because of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

referring to this:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-dictionary. 
In C#, Dictionary has no sort method. You must separately acquire the element and sort them.
Something useful is here:
[How do you sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ you could write it like this:

```
var Ids = (from key in chunkedStates.Keys
           select Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(key))).Distinct().ToList();
```