# sort dictionary based on value using Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict:

```
self.currentMsg={'Decimal Label value':'','SDI value':'','Label format':''}

for i in range (self.firstRowIdx, self.lastRowIdx) :
        self.currentMsg['Decimal Label value']=self.xlManager.getCellValue(i,LABEL_COL_IDX)


self.currentMsg['SDI value']= SDIValue=self.xlManager.getCellValue(i,SDI_COL_IDX)
        self.currentMsg['Label format']=LabelFormat=self.xlManager.getCellValue(i,FORMAT_COL_IDX)
 sorted_x = sorted(self.currentMsg.items(),key=operator.itemgetter('Decimal Label value'))
        print(sorted_x)
```

I would like to sort the dict based on increasing value of 'Decimal Label value'.

I've tried this:

```
sorted_x = sorted(self.currentMsg.items(), key=itemgetter(''Decimal Label value''))
```

but I get this error

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

then I've tried this:

```
sorted_x = sorted(self.currentMsg.items(), key=itemgetter('0'))
```

but the dict is still not sorted.
the console shows:

```
[('Decimal Label value', 324.0), ('Label format', 'BNR'), ('SDI value', 'XX')]
[('Decimal Label value', 331.0), ('Label format', 'BNR'), ('SDI value', 'XX')]

[('Decimal Label value', 312.0), ('Label format', 'BNR'), ('SDI value', 'XX')]
```

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-value?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have a *list* of dicts, not *a* dict.

Therefore, try:

```
sorted_x = sorted(self.currentMsg, 
    key=operator.itemgetter('Decimal Label value'))
```

---

On second thought, since you are using `self.currentMsg.items()` and it did not raise an `AttributeError`, it appears `self.currentMsg` is probably a dict. 
Then `self.currentMsg.items()` would be a tuple of key/value pairs. This contradicts your first statement, since it only shows a sequence of 3 dicts.

To better answer your question, we need to see what `self.currentMsg` really looks like.

Comment: I've tried this but I get this error ,TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @user3801697: and you have tuples where exactly? Please post a reproducible sample in your question, something that can be used directly.