# Sort Three Dimensional Dictionary by value in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, dictionary

I have the following three dimensional Dictionary.

```
class CopyDir
{
    public class MyFileInfo
    {
        public int Num{ get; set; }
        public long Size { get; set; }
    }
    public static Dictionary<string, MyFileInfo> logInfo;
```

I want to sort the dictionary based on size Field.

logInfo.OrderBy says 
Error   CS1061  'Dictionary' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Where are three dimensions? I only see a single linear dictionary.

Comment: `logInfo.OrderBy(x=>x.Value.Size)` doesnt that work??

Comment: @MohitShrivastava it says error Dictionary<string,CopyDir.MyFileInfo> does not contain definition for OrderBy and no extension...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you sort a dictionary by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @Sebi no unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it easily using LINQ extensions. We are sorting the values of the dictionary.

```
var sorted = logInfo.Values.OrderBy(x=>x.Size);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *represent* the dictionary (e.g. print out on the console) 
with their values ordered, try uing *Linq*

```
   var result = logInfo
     .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value.Size)
     .ThenBy(pair => pair.Num); // in case of tie, let's order by Num
```

Test

```
   var test = result
     .Select(item => $"{item.Key,6}: Size = {item.Size,6}; Num = {item.Num,6}");

   Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, test));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
logInfo.OrderBy(x=>x.Value.Size);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorted = logInfo.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value.Size);
```