# Insertion sort of a dictionary

Tags: python, class, sorting, object, dictionary

I need to sort a dictionary containing a set of keys and values, the keys all differ as do the values and I need to sort the values though insertion sort before exporting to a file.

So far all I can find is people sorting either lists of multiple dictionaries where all the keys being sorted are the same.

my code is below:

```
playerName = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m']
playerScore = [12,15,31,26,94,13,16,12,11,85,70,14,56]
player = dict(zip(playerName, playerScore))

print(player)
```

how do i now sort this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply use `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you sort a dictionary by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Dictionaries are *unordered* and cannot be sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a dictionary, consider this:

```
playerName = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
playerScore = [12, 15, 31, 26, 94, 13, 16, 12, 11, 85, 70, 14, 56] 

player = sorted(zip(playerName, playerScore), key=lambda x: x[0])

print(player)
[('a', 12),
 ('b', 15),
 ('c', 31),
 ('d', 26),
 ('e', 94),
 ('f', 13),
 ('g', 16),
 ('h', 12),
 ('i', 11),
 ('j', 85),
 ('k', 70),
 ('l', 14),
 ('m', 56)]
```

Just call python's inbuilt `sorted` function and pass a lambda function as a parameter so it knows what to sort on.

---

If you want to construct an ordered dictionary, you could use `collections.OrderedDict` (python < 3.6):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

player_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(zip(playerName, playerScore), key=lambda x: x[0]))
print(player_dict)
OrderedDict([('a', 12),
             ('b', 15),
             ('c', 31),
             ('d', 26),
             ('e', 94),
             ('f', 13),
             ('g', 16),
             ('h', 12),
             ('i', 11),
             ('j', 85),
             ('k', 70),
             ('l', 14),
             ('m', 56)])
```

It's still a dictionary, and supports all `dict` methods:

```
print(isinstance(player_dict, dict)
True
```

---

Note that dictionaries in python3.6+ are ordered by default, so just pass a list of tuples from `sorted` to `dict` and you'll get the same sorted result.

Comment: Could I bother you to vote your conscience on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165056/2336654

Comment: I sent you an email instead (-:

Comment: @JohnGalt Ah... thanks for letting me know I need to delete this thread. And thank you....

Comment: @JohnGalt It might have looked like a monologue but I was definitely replying to comments there!

Answer (score 0):

i think better to use playerscores as keys. if you use palyerscores as keys then you can get the keys and you can sort the keys. then you can find the best scorer and lowest scorer.

```
playerName = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m']
playerScore = [12,15,31,26,94,13,16,12,11,85,70,14,56]
player = dict(zip(playerScore, playerName))
PList = []
for i in player.keys():
    PList.append(i)
PList.sort()
print(PList)
print(player)
```