# How do you output a dictionary's keys in order by value from highest to lowest when all values are integers

Tags: dictionary, python-3.7

I want to have at the end of it the keys for the dictionary organised by the values from lowest to highest value. This is needed in python 3.7.1.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried, and its output.

Comment: I don't know where to begin

Answer (score -1):

You can try to look for other question on stackoverflow that kinda answer your question.

I found these:

- [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)
- [How do you sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-value?rq=1)
- [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary?rq=1)
- [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

---

You can also try to look into the documentation of python:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0265/

Comment: if it's a duplicate, vote to close and mark as a duplicate

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21324850. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a short heads up, I will quickly delete this comment.