# Reading characters from a string and counting each one of them

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary

The issue i have with my code is as following: i cannot get my head around how to read each character and sum each up in one **int** for everyone at the end of all rotations. *Here is my code*:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SortedDictionary<string, int> text = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
        string[] characters = Console.ReadLine()
            .Split()
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var character in characters)
        {
            if (text.ContainsKey(character))
            {
                text[character]++;
            }
            else
            {
                text.Add(character, 1);
            }
        }
        foreach (var character in text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{character.Key} -> {character.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

I am reading here how many times a string exists in the Dictionary. What i need to get, written above, is different. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Examples
text t -> 2
 e -> 1
 x -> 1

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine().GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())`?

Comment: @clcto i am receiving for example: text -> 1
when i write "text" into the compiler

Comment: @AluanHaddad Where should i use that and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Split()` is splitting on new lines by default so `characters` contains a single string with the whole line in it. If you want each of the characters, just get rid of the `Split` (and change the Dictionary KeyType to `char` to match the values):

```
SortedDictionary<char, int> text = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
char[] characters = Console.ReadLine().ToArray();
// ...
```

https://www.ideone.com/hnMSv1

Since `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>` you actually don't even need to convert the characters into an array:

```
SortedDictionary<char, int> text = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
string line = Console.ReadLine();
foreach( char character in line )
// ...
```

https://www.ideone.com/nLyBfC

Comment: Thank you very much for the help so far! One question is in my head. Why doesnt it sort the values/keys in descending order anymore? I see it is still a SortedDictionary, but it doesnt sort them.

Comment: It is sorting them - it sorts by the keys not the values. `e < t < x`

Comment: how do i change the sorting to be done by values and not by keys then?

Comment: If you have other questions, they deserve their own questions. But the one you just asked is a duplicate, so see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: Thanks! Found the solution to my problem. Here it is:
foreach (var character in text.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{character.Key} -> {character.Value}");
            }

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ here because any string consists of char element. So, string type implements `IEnumerable<char>` interface:

```
string str = "aaabbc";
var res = str
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .ToDictionary(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

The example below demonstrates how you can get it without casting to dictionary but projecting an anonymous type and sort the number of characters in descending order:

```
var res2 = str
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Select(d => new { d.Key, Count = d.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```